# How to delete chromedriver session created in the docker?

Tags: docker, selenium, grid

After the execution of automation I need to delete the driver session created in the docker

Comment: Do you mean killing the chrome driver executable process? Or closing the chrome browser window?

Comment: please give more information about your question...

Comment: After the execution complete, I can see some of the browser instances are still occupied, so I wanted to kill those browser session to free the instance